# Searching multiple columns, several words in first column

Tags: php, mysql, search

Hey I got problem with my(found) search code. 
If I search for something that is split into two columns like Name and Last name,
it only works if the first name is only One name(word).
For example If I got a Name column with two names such as Nancy Dandry,
and a LastName column with 5 names, Tomson Craig John McGee Name,
I can search for it only if I use one name(word) from the Name Column.

**Example**

**:Search Field:** Nancy John McGee Name = **Results**

**:Search Field:** Dandry Tomson  John Tomson  = **Results**

**:Search Field:** Nancy Dandry = **No Results**

**:Search Field:** Nancy Dandry Tomson = **No Results.**

Basically if the Name column has two or more words and I search for two or more words, I get no results at all.
How do I got about fixing this? I really can't find anyway, I've searched all over...
I believe the Culprit is the little snippet of code below, but I'm not sure.

I've been trying to tackle this issue several times for a few months and given up on it every time :& I've tried all the other options, but this is the closest I've been to solving it... Sounds like I'm building a rocket, but yeah... :)

```
 $output = ' ' ;
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$x = "";
$construct = "";  

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="Name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND LastName LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}
```

The Form I'm using

```
<form action='sear.php' method='GET'>
                            <center>
                                    <h1> Search</h1>
                                            <input type='text' size='50' name='search'></br></br>
                                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' ></br></br></br>
                            </center>
                    </form>
```

Full Php Code

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term is too short!";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","Name_Name","Password");
mysql_select_db("Database_Test");
    $output = ' ' ;
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$x = "";
$construct = "";  

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="Name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND LastName LIKE '%$search_each%'";




}

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM Information WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Excuse for not finding the result... None";
else
{ 

echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

$per_page = 10;
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start']: '';
$max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT id, Name, LastName FROM Information WHERE $construct ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$id = $runrows ['id'];
$Name = $runrows ['Name'];
$LastName = $runrows ['LastName'];

$output .= ' <div class="Name">' . $Name . ' </div> <div class="LastName">' . $LastName . ' </div> ';



}

//Pagination Starts
echo "<center>";

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

$adjacents = 3;
$last = $max_pages - 1;

if($max_pages > 1)
{   
//previous button
if (!($start<=0)) 
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$prev'>Prev</a> ";    

//pages 
if ($max_pages < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
{
$i = 0;   
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}  
$i = $i + $per_page;                 
}
}
elseif($max_pages > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
{
//close to beginning; only hide later pages
if(($start/$per_page) < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
{
$i = 0;
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;                                       
}

}
//in middle; hide some front and some back
elseif($max_pages - ($adjacents * 2) > ($start / $per_page) && ($start / $per_page) > ($adjacents * 2))
{
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                 
for ($counter = ($start/$per_page)+1; $counter < ($start / $per_page) + $adjacents + 2; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}   
$i = $i + $per_page;                
}

}
//close to end; only hide early pages
else
{
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                
for ($counter = ($start / $per_page) + 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";   
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;              
}
}
}

//next button
if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page))
echo " <a href='sear.php?search=$search&submit=Search+names+keyword&start=$next'>Next</a> ";    
}   
echo "</center>";
} 
} 
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `OR`, and yes, you are vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: @Ghost I've tried OR but it gives me all results with the name I search. If I search for One Two Three  it doesn't give me One Two Three, it gives me all results containing any of those strings :& Yeah I'll need to try and fix SQL Injection issue after this :P

Comment: provide sqlfiddle with data sample please

Comment: Why not concat() the Name and LastName in your WHERE statement? `SELECT * FROM Information WHERE CONCAT(Name, ' ', LastName) LIKE '%$search%'; as a lite example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a fulltext index across `(first_name, last_name)`, eg:

`alter table names add fulltext name (first_name, last_name);`

and then query against it like so:

```
select * 
  from names 
    where match (first_name, last_name) 
      against('+Nancy +Dandry' in boolean mode);

select * 
  from names 
    where match (first_name, last_name) 
      against('+Nancy +Dandry +Tomson'in boolean mode);
select * 
  from names 
    where match (first_name, last_name) 
      against('+Dandry +Tomson +John +Tomson'in boolean mode);
select * 
  from names 
    where match (first_name, last_name) 
      against('+Nancy +John +McGee +Name'in boolean mode);
```

All of which will return matching rows, whereas:

```
select * 
  from names 
    where match (first_name, last_name) 
      against('+Nancy +Cylon'in boolean mode);
```

Will not return any matches, because the `+` signs in front of the name elements will ensure that only results that match all those word are included. [heres an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f872/5)